# How to Querying Another Application's CP Safely

Tags: android, mysql, android-contentprovider

I have two applications and I want to create a query from App A to get App B's info. 
This is a very simple process as shown below, but i wanted to double check with the community and get some constructive criticism. Is there a better way?

Thank you.

This code gets the name of someone in my DB.

```
private Cursor getData() {


final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_PATH);
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "foo" };
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = null;;


ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    return  resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

}
```

Comment: Well, there aren't all that many options. What specifically are you concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it should work if the system is aware of a content provider that has the authority you've specified, *and* that provider recognizes TABLE_PATH, *and* the provider recognizes "_id" and "foo" as valid column names.

However, you seem to be asking several different questions:

1. Is this a safe way to query another app's content provider? Oh yes; It is by far the most preferred way to get data from another app.
2. "This code gets the name of someone in my DB". Actually, that's a slight misstatement. The code runs a query against the content provider that has the authority AUTHORITY, and against an entity in the provider that is named TABLE_PATH. No database is necessary, although content providers often store their data in an SQLite database. All that the CP has to do is establish an authority and respond to incoming content URIs.